# Serialize a List<Foo> where Foo is ISerializable

Tags: c#, serialization, collections

I'm trying to serialize a `List<Foo>` where `Foo` implements `ISerializable` and I want its own serialization/deserialization routines to be followed, which are quite complex, but work fine. Here's how far I've gotten:

```
[Serializable]
public class FooList : List<Foo>, ISerializable
{
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {

        Foo[] tempAr = ToArray();

        // How do I populate these?
        SerializationInfo[] infoAr;
        StreamingContext[] ctxtAr;

        info.AddValue("infoAr", infoAr, typeof(SerializationInfo[]));
        info.AddValue("ctxtAr", ctxtAr, typeof(StreamingContext[]));
    }

    public SerializableList(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        SerializationInfo[] infoAr = (SerializationInfo[])info.GetValue("infoAr", typeof(SerializationInfo[]));
        StreamingContext[] ctxtAr = (StreamingContext[])info.GetValue("ctxtAr", typeof(StreamingContext[]));

        int n = infoAr.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            Add(new Foo(infoAr[i], ctxtAr[i]));
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to serialize this in a way that the routines in the class are followed, rather than just binary converts.

Comment: Sounds good. What's the *problem*?

Comment: I'm having trouble populating `infoAr` and `ctxtAr` in the first method, @Dmitry.

Comment: OK. And what is the problem? Any exceptions, undesired behaviour?

Comment: I don't know how to populate them in the first place. Like, how do I declare "empty" `SerializationInfo`s and `Streaming Context`s? Is `new()` sufficient? @Dmitry